# How to use dates as X axis with Chart.js even when there is no Y axis value related

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I would like the chart to always have a value on the final X axis,

I can't use it as "distribution: 'series'" because it goes out of scale,

I can't always guess which value to put as "time: {min / max}" so that it exceeds the last value, and I also can't manually define what data will be displayed on the Y axis.

Is it possible to define data like the following example?

X axis values:

```
1 - 2020-04-01
2 - 2020-04-03
3 - 2020-04-08
4 - 2020-04-10
5 - 2020-04-15
```

With Y axis such as:

```
x   x           x  x       x
|_____________|____________|__
04-01       04-07         04-15
```

Right now, I defined these three values on the axis `04-01 / 04-07 / 04-15` manually, even if none of the data has `04-07` as date.

[image]

Comment: my code: https://jsfiddle.net/fo2pmzrj/

Answer (score 2):

From your code I see that you tried different approaches, including [`ticks.autoskip`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/?h=autoskip#tick-configuration) and [`ticks.maxTicksLimit`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#tick-configuration-options). Both of these option limit the number of tick labels if required but don't guarantee that the last label corresponds to the last data point.

To solve this in a clean way, you have to implement your own [`ticks.maxTicksLimit`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#tick-configuration-options) on the `xAxis`. This can be done in the following way.

1. Generate a `labels` array out of the times contained in your data. This array should contain the data start and end time and the specified number of equally spread times between both (see function `createLabels` in your amended code below).
2. Tell Chart.js to generates ticks on the `xAxis` from given labels by defining [`tick.sources: 'labels'`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#ticks-source).

```js
const data = [
  { t: new Date("2015-3-15 13:30"), y: 12 },
  { t: new Date("2015-3-25 13:20"), y: 21 },
  { t: new Date("2015-3-26 13:20"), y: 21 },
  { t: new Date("2015-3-27 13:20"), y: 21 },
  { t: new Date("2015-5-14 13:20"), y: 21 },
  { t: new Date("2015-7-25 14:12"), y: 32 },
  { t: new Date("2015-08-01 14:12"), y: 40 },
  { t: new Date("2015-08-10 14:12"), y: 40 },
  { t: new Date("2015-08-11 14:12"), y: 40 },
  { t: new Date("2015-09-20 14:12"), y: 40 }
];

function createLabels(maxTicksLimit) {
  const times = data.map(o => o.t.getTime());
  const startTime = times[0];
  const endTime = times[times.length -1];
  const tickGap = ( endTime - startTime) / (maxTicksLimit - 1);
  const labels = [startTime];
  for (let i = 1; i < maxTicksLimit - 1; i++) {
    labels.push(startTime + i * tickGap);
  }
  labels.push(endTime);
  return labels;
}

var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("examChart"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: createLabels(12),
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Demo',
      fill: false,
      data: data,
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        ticks: {
          source: 'labels',
          minRotation: 45
        },
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
          displayFormats: {
            day: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
          },
          tooltipFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          suggestedMin: 0
        },
        gridLines: {
          zeroLineColor: "rgba(0,255,0,1)"
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'y axis'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="width:50%;">
  <canvas id="examChart"></canvas>
</div>
```